# Detecting unusable type annotation

Tags: python, type-hinting

In Python (3.6+) When using a colon by mistake in trying to initialize a dict, it is interpreted as valid syntax, likely indicating a type hint. However, the information is just thrown away and appears to be unretrievable.

```
>>> a: int
>>> b: 3
>>> d= {}
>>> d['something']: 4
>>> d
{}
>>> __annotations__
{'a': <class 'int'>, 'b': 3}
```

Is there a way, using tools from the Python standard library (excluding the re module), to somehow parse this code and retrieve the information that was thrown away, thereby identifying that the type hint syntax was misused.

I did file a bug about this (https://bugs.python.org/issue41488) but it was closed as being irrelevant.

Comment: You are looking for `ast.parse`. So , check out `ast.parse("d['something']:4")`

Comment: I don't see why you would need runtime support, rather than simply fixing your code.

Comment: @chepner It is not for my code, I am working on a tool to help beginners. https://aroberge.blogspot.com/2020/08/identifying-misleading-type-hints.html